# Swap two elements of an array function

Tags: c

Can you help me by telling me what is wrong with this? Why is the swap function not working?

```
void swap(int a[], int b, int c) {
    int temp = a[b];
    a[b] = a[c];
    a[b] = temp;
}

void bubble1 (int a[], int N){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
            swap(a,i,i+1);
        }
    }
}


void main() {
    int N = 11;
    int a[12]={5,3,12,4,25,10,14,35,2,8,13};

    bubble1 (a,N);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

If I don't use the swap function and do the swapping manually in the "bubble" function it works. However if I use the swap it doesn't work, even though it's exactly the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try stepping through `swap()` on a piece of paper, and you will soon see the problem.

Comment: do not use an extra variable for size use swap(int a[], size_t size) and calculate size of the array you are using by #define ARRAY_LENGTH(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) a is the array

Answer (score 8):

```
 int temp = a[b];
 a[b] = a[c];
 a[b] = temp;
```

Simple typo, you are assigning to `a[b]` twice. The second one should be `a[c]`

Comment: lol i feel ashamed.sry

Comment: Don't be. However, go through it, rewrite it and think thoroughly to avoid mistakes such as this one.